# Android giving html embed video url to browser

Tags: android, html

I am getting the following video url from server

```
<iframe width=\"480\" height=\"270\" src=\"http://staging.snagfilms.com/modules/html5player.jsp?filmId=ed9195a0-a748-11e0-a92a-0026bb61d036&w=500\" frameborder=\"0\" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Now I need to play the url in Andorid browser. I am not much good with HTML. Can any one help me how to format the above url and give it to the browser

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to do the same thing but could not get the video to play. I ended up using a link with an image like this:

```
<a href="http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aniukekGDi8"><img src="meet_developers_video_jules.png" width="300" height="168" style="border-style:solid; border-color:#ccc; border-width:1px; margin-top:5px"></a>
```